# Как передать переменную в vagrant для ansible provision

Tags: развертывание, ansible, vagrant, devops, gitlab-ci

Привтествую! Пытаюсь атоматизировать установку пакета на ВМ Vagrant с ansible provision.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
 config.ssh.insert_key = false  
 config.vm.box = "my-box"
 pkg_name = "screen"

  config.vm.define "server_pkg" do |server_pkg|
    server_pkg.vm.hostname = "server"
    server_pkg.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.2"
    server_pkg.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
      ansible.playbook = "ansible/repo.yml"
      ansible_verbose = true
      ansible.extra_vars = {
        name_pkg: "#{pkg_name}"
      }

    end         
  end
end
```

Сбственно ансиблу передаю название пакета для установки, выше в Vagrantfile, следовательно мне надо править этот файл какждый раз года я хочу установить новый пакет.Но эта же переменная болтается на хосте! Как ее прокинуть в Vagrantfile?

Comment: Я с вагрантом не работал, поэтому не понял куда и чё ты хочешь править. Дополни вопрос для тупых чё именно ты хочешь каждый раз менять.

Answer (score 0):

Желание было передать переменную с хоста в ansible provision в секцию Vagrantfile

```
ansible.extra_vars = {
        name_pkg: "ВОТ СЮДА!!"
      }
```

Законченный вид, как оказалось, такой

```
 ansible.extra_vars = {         
        name_pkg: "#{ENV['pkg']}"       
}
```

и ваграт вызываем

```
pkg=$name_pkg vagrant up
```